# Alias and rewriterules working together

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, httpd.conf, short-url

I have multiple domain names pointing at one Apache2 virtual host:

```
ServerName domain1.com
ServerAlias domain2.com
ServerAlias domain3.com
```

To always display the same url I use a rewriterule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain1.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain1.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Finally I have a alias like this:

```
Alias /niceurl /long/path/to/index.php
```

Everything works as fine, except that when a user visits `domain2.com/niceurl/foo`, the url displayed in the browser will be `domain1.com/path/to/index.php/foo`, rather than `domain1.com/niceurl/foo`

I should add that the other cases work like expected, in other words:

```
domain2.com/foo => domain1.com/foo
domain1.com/shorturl/bar => domain1.com/shorturl/bar
```

Is there a clever way to achieve what I want? Thanks for any hints!

Comment: It seems like the problem is actually related to this http://serverfault.com/questions/212071/serveralias-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is creating a symlink, if you have access to your document root:

```
ln -s /<path to application> /<document root>/foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a Query String Append (QSA) on a domain redirect?

Try your rule without it:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain1.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: You are right about the QSA, however that doesn't solve the issue. The domain redirect works fine, but the "niceurl" part is not preserved.

 (The reason I want full urls to work is that the domain name is an IDN, and many people are still used to replacing å with a, ö with o, etc in domain names, hence there will be links like that pointing to the site)